# Mount my own samba share?

Tags: mount, samba

I would like to access my local data, which is exported as a samba share, as if I am a samba client. Basically, how do I correctly mount my own samba share? The following mount (device) parameters:

```
//localhost/SHARE_NAME
//127.0.0.1/SHARE_NAME 
//IP_OF_SAMBA_SERVER/SHARE_NAME
```

All result in "`mount: special device <device> does not exist`".

Other clients have no trouble connecting/mounting the share. gvfs/Nautilus mounting is also working just fine. Ubuntu 12.04 in use.

Comment: To access a samba share, don't you need to preface it with "smb:"?  As-in "smb://127.0.0.1/SHARE_NAME"

Comment: The linux smb client doesn't support the smb:// prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the comments and answers. Looking at the issue with fresh eyes today, it appears to be a simple mount type (-t) option issue. All of the suggested device parameters, including `//HOSTNAME/SHARE_NAME`, are okay when used in the following mount command:
 
`sudo mount -t cifs -o guest //LOCALHOST/SHARE_NAME //DIRECTORY/MOUNT_POINT`
As for the device name variations - it seems best practice to use `127.0.0.1` to refer to the host.

Answer (score 1):

from console:

```
#mount -t smbfs -o username=username,"password=password" //127.0.0.1/SHARE_NAME  /mnt/tmp
```

Comment: I believe that CIFS protocol is the successor to the SMB protocol and that smbfs is now deprecated and unmaintained. Refer to mount.cifs